# Is the board game "Snakes and Ladders" kosher?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, games-toys

It appears to be a game based on the Hindu religion. Here is an excerpt from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_ladders#History):

> The game was popular in ancient India by the name Moksha Patam. It was
> also associated with traditional Hindu philosophy contrasting karma
> and kama, or destiny and desire. It emphasized destiny, as opposed to
> games such as pachisi, which focused on life as a mixture of skill
> (free will) and luck. The underlying ideals of the game inspired a
> version introduced in Victorian England in 1892. The game has also
> been interpreted and used as a tool for teaching the effects of good
> deeds versus bad. The board was covered with symbolic images used in
> ancient India, the top featuring gods, angels, and majestic beings,
> while the rest of the board was covered with pictures of animals,
> flowers and people. The ladders represented virtues such as
> generosity, faith, and humility, while the snakes represented vices
> such as lust, anger, murder, and theft. The morality lesson of the
> game was that a person can attain liberation (Moksha) through doing
> good, whereas by doing evil one will be reborn as lower forms of life.
> The number of ladders was less than the number of snakes as a reminder
> that a path of good is much more difficult to tread than a path of
> sins. Presumably, reaching the last square (number 100) represented
> the attainment of Moksha (spiritual liberation).

So, is it kosher to play this game according to Jewish law?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? 

Comment: But we believe the same thing?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Apologies, I meant the *etzem* notions of *nisayon* and progression.